# Mediawiki: Error sending mail

Tags: php, email, mediawiki

I'm absolutely new to MediaWiki. I've installed it, set up smtp settings and trying to create a new user with sending him a password by email. But I'm getting the following error:

`Account creation error
Error sending mail: Validation failed for: =?UTF-8?Q?=D0=92=D0=B8=D0=BA=D0=B8=20=D0=BC=D1=83=D0=B6=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B3=D0=BE=20=D1=85=D1=80=D0=B8=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B8=D0=B0=D0=BD=D1=81=D0=BA=D0=BE=D0=B3=D0=BE=20=D1=81=D0=BE=D0=BE=D0=B1=D1=89=D0=B5=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D0=B0=20"=D0=9F=D1=83=D1=82=D1=8C"?=`

My email settings in `LocalSettings.php` are as follows:

```
$wgEnableEmail      = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail  = true; # UPO
$wgAllowHTMLEmail   = false;
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;
$wgEnableUserEmail = true;
$wgPasswordSender = "robot@domain.org";
$wgEmailAuthentication = true;
$wgEnotifUserTalk = true;
$wgEnotifWatchlist     = false; # UPO

$wgEmergencyContact = 'my@email.com';
$wgPasswordSender   = 'my@email.com';

$wgEmailAuthentication = true;
$wgSMTP = array(
 'host'     => "mail.domain.org",
 'IDHost'   => "domain.org",
 'port'     => 25,
 'auth'     => false,
 'username' => "robot@domain.org,
 'password' => "password"
);
```

The rest of the settings is default. Also I installed PEAR's Mail package. Could please somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that there was installed PEAR's `Mail` package. The package is intended for `PHP 4.4.9`, while I have Mediawiki 1.24 which works with `PHP 5.3.2`.
So I tried to install PEAR's `Mail2` package, which works with `PHP 5.0.0`. But it occurred that Mediawiki won't works with it.

The solution was to install `SwiftMailer` extension. Mediawiki plays perfectly with it. In fact there are talks to include that into the core of Mediawiki to handle all mailing operations. The installation guide is here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SwiftMailer